# Residues of $e^z/ \cosh(z)$ not matching numeric solution

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm integrating $\frac{e^z dz}{\cosh(z)}$ along a circle of radius $5$ (centered at the origin).

Solving for $\cosh(z) = 0$, one gets $z = (\frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi)i$.  Only four of these lie within my circle ($\pi i/2,\ 3\pi i/2 -\pi i/2, -3\pi i/2$).  We can evaluate the residue of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as $\frac{f(x)}{g'(x)}$, which, in this case, is

$$\frac{e^z}{\sinh(z)}$$

But if you throw the poles into this, you get $1$ for each of these, which means the sum or residuals is 4, meaning the integral should be equal to

$$2\pi i\ \Sigma_i (\text{res}_i) = 2\pi i (4) = 8\pi i$$

But when I evaluate the integral numerically (trapezoidal rule, one million intervals) with a Python program I wrote I get $2\pi$, which suggests the residual-sum should be $\frac{1}{i} = -i$.

Does naive numeric integration fail for complex numbers (this seems unlikely), or have I screwed something up?

Comment: I tried it and it works, also Python. This is what I integrate: $5i\int_0^{2\pi}dt\;e^{it}f(5e^{it})$ and the result is $25.1327i\approx 8\pi i$

Comment: Do numerical techniques work for complex integrals too?

Comment: @mathlover Sure, just sum real and imaginary parts separately. Problems can arise of course, for example if the real part is supposed to be exactly zero (as in this case) it probably won't be exactly zero from your numerical method. But it still works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing it as a real integral, you have

$$\int_{t=0}^{t=2\pi} \frac{e^{5e^{it}} d(5e^{it})}{\cosh(5e^{it})} = 5i \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{e^{5e^{it}} e^{it}}{\cosh(5e^{it})} dt.$$

Computing this numerically in Matlab as

```
5*i*integral(@(t) exp(5*exp(i*t)).*exp(i*t)./(cosh(5*exp(i*t))),0,2*pi)
```

results in

```
-0.000000000000007 +25.132741228718409i
```

dividing that by pi results in

```
-0.000000000000002 + 8.000000000000020i
```

So Matlab is giving me essentially $8 \pi i$ as expected.

So there's something wrong with your program or (more likely) with the integrand that you put into it.